# How OpenLayers handles invalid geometries

Tags: openlayers, geometry

What do OpenLayers do if I import invalid Geometries? I have some LineStrings in an area type feature and somehow OpenLayers does not care.
I can see and interact with it. I also have a lot of self-intersecting polygons, which are also invalid, if am not wrong.

So even if OpenLayers can handle them, I'm running into an exception in a third party lib called polygon-clipping.

I do area calculation with this lib and at some point I get an "Unable to find segment" error. Figured out that it caused by one self-intersecting Polygon (out of over 700 other self-intersecting polygons and almost 15000 polygons). So there are some weird edge cases with invalid geometries.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what do you want to do with invalid geometries. Do you want to skip them, repair them ...?

Comment: OpenLayers uses the coordinates it is given without any validation (you can even draw self-intersecting polygons).  You could use a third-party utility such as turf kink to check and unkinkPolygon to correct (convert kinked to MultiPolygon) if having valid geometry is important.

Comment: I expected Openlayers to throw some errors... So if self-intersecting polygons are invalid, then I will get a wrong value from getArea() f. e., right? I guess I need to validate them before I start my calculations, thx for the Information!